# Pre-registration of data that is already collected

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey, pre-registration

I collected survey data in late 2018 through mid 2019. With the pandemic and other projects, I haven't had time to do anything but enter the data. I have not yet analyzed the data, or even looked at basic descriptives or correlations. I do have hypotheses and theory that were generated in 2018.

Is it too late to pre-register the study? When I collected the data, pre-registration was not a mainstream practice. Regrettably, I didn't pre-register then.

Comment: What would be the purpose of pre-registering in your situation?

Answer (score 3):

Pre-registration of the data analysis depends on the level of contact you have had with the data. Given you haven't analyzed the data, this is still essentially a primary data analysis. However, the collection of data before pre-registration and the length in time between collection/analysis makes it difficult for this project to be pre-registered in that way. This is because you are supposed to pre-register how you will sample, stopping rules, etc. in advance. Obviously that is not the case here since the data was already collected.

If you are really worried about scrutiny about the timeline of your project, the most obvious solution to me is to pre-register this as a [secondary data analysis](https://open.lnu.se/index.php/metapsychology/article/view/2625) instead, where the [pre-registration templates on places like OSF](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1p6UE2b0D0ON4XEccOCOU1pdaCTiyGLOfP-g-8Ayxylk/edit#heading=h.fwbi14d4b65g) will ask what your level of contact is with the data anyway after the data has been collected.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure if we could call that a secondary data analysis, as it's the original study for which the data has been collected in the first place. I'd tend to call that a retrospective registration, and I'm not sure if OSF accepts this kind of submission. But in any case, the obvious problem is how to avoid to involuntarily mislead readers about the timeline, so no matter the solution (registration as reprospective or secondary data analysis), the situation should be made explicit and abundantly clear.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the only more flexible pre-registration that accounts for this is the [open-ended registration](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_hdYTyOj90WOJq1dI7UTpVmqwCGHenFc5DBjmAdpXGg/edit#heading=h.fwbi14d4b65g), which is essentially just a semi-blank doc you fill in yourself. Perhaps OP can combine elements of the SDA format (supplying dates of data collection, etc.) and filling other vital information as needed. My only concern is that the primary data versions explicitly ask you to register things in advance that OP has already done.